# Resizing divs depending on information inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I have a container where I want to hold information (which would be updated regularly). But sometimes, I might want this information to be long or short, and for this I cant have a fixed height on my container, so depending on the amount of text/information it should resize. Here's my script.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>LoL Champs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Belleza' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<!-- NAVIGATION --> 
<div id="nav-bar">
    <div id="nav-bar-title">LoL Champs</div>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Champs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Guides</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Model Viewer</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lists</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- END NAVIGATION -->

<div id="main-body">
<div id="nav-body-divider"></div>

<p id="home-body-title">News</p>
<!-- News Container -->
<div id="news-container">

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
/** MAIN PAGE CONFIG CSS **/

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-height: 1050px;
    font-size: 100%;
}

html { 
  background: url(../images/JinxBG.jpg) 0 0 fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

p {
    color: white;
}

a:link {color: inherit;}
a:visited {color: inherit;}
a:active {color: inherit;}
a {text-decoration: none;}
/** MAIN CSS **/

/**NAVIGATION**/
#nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #A62D2D;
    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 9px black;
    font-size: 100%;
    max-height: 10%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#nav-bar-title {
    font-family: 'Sansita One';
    color: #262424;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0.3%;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    max-width: 16%;
    margin-top: 1.2%;
}

#nav-bar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #2E2C2C;
    font-family: 'Belleza';
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    left: 15%;
    line-height: 0%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    top: 50%;
}
#nav-bar li {
    margin-right: 45px;
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
#nav-bar li:hover {
    color: #C7C7C7;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

/** END NAVIGATION **/

/** MAIN TEXT BODY **/
#nav-body-divider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #B55050;

}

#main-body {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 90%;
    background: #A62D2D;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
}

/** MAIN BODY NEWS **/

#home-body-title {
    font-size: 2.4em;
    font-family: Belleza;
    color: #C98A5D;
    position: relative;
    left: 3%;
    top: 0%;
}

#news-container {
    width: 45%;
    height: 40%;
    background: #CF4040;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    position: relative;
    left: 3%;
}
```

I want to resize `news-container` so that it adapts to the amount of stuff in it, but resize it only on height. The width should stay the same. Also, if the div will be bigger, how can I move the objects that will be below that div to accommodate further down on the page and make space for the big container?

Cheers, Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never set a height on anything. Always let the content grow naturally. http://jsfiddle.net/LQkj3/

```
<div id="news-container">
  <p>
    This is the news section! height will automatically grow depending on the amount of data! you should NEVER control height with pixels or percentage! always let the content grow it automatically.
  </p>
</div>


<style>
#news-container { width: 45%; background: #CF4040; -webkit-border-radius: 7px; -moz-border-radius: 7px; border-radius: 7px; position: relative; left: 3%;  padding: .5em 1em; }
</style>
```

...Unless of course you need a scrollable container (like @griegs suggested). ;)

Then you could put a max-width: 10em; or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:200px; border: 1px solid black; max-height: 400px; overflow: scroll">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et iaculis dui, id dapibus nibh. Phasellus sollicitudin urna non elementum aliquam. Vivamus nec aliquet quam. Mauris eget sollicitudin tellus, at dictum tellus. Donec sed porttitor quam, in suscipit nisl. Praesent vestibulum auctor turpis quis vulputate. Quisque eget erat vel tellus pretium bibendum. Mauris feugiat urna nec pharetra bibendum. Integer consectetur nisl cursus aliquam rhoncus. Mauris vulputate pulvinar commodo. Mauris placerat enim erat, a dignissim metus laoreet quis. Aenean nec ipsum neque. Proin adipiscing tellus ut nisi rutrum tempus. Aliquam erat volutpat. In dignissim consectetur tellus sit amet sagittis. Nam ac quam id nunc adipiscing commodo. 
</div>
```

Remove the `overflow` and the `max-height` if these are not important to you.  I put them in to demonstrate that pure css should be all you need.

As the div grows, the elements below it will be pushed down so long as they are not positioned absolute or floated etc.